# What is the timezone of publishedAt in Snippet of Youtube API response?

Tags: youtube-data-api

Editing to include the API response too.

Request to API

```
base = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos'
params = {
            'part' : 'snippet,contentDetails',
            'id': <List of Video IDs>,
            'key':gkey
}

response = requests.get(base, params).json()

Sample Snippet


{'publishedAt': ***'2017-11-13T06:06:22Z'***,
 'channelId': 'UCDYetMc6gOLkhIiNzFyrJPA',
 'title': 'Capítulo 12 | MasterChef 2017',
```

What is the TIMEZONE of the `response['items'][0]['snippet']['publishedAt']` ?

I have searched the entire documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos)
but couldn't find this CRITICAL info.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It would be helpful to edit your question to show what the API call returns. Perhaps the timezone information is present, since it's a standard ISO 8601 datetime format. Perhaps it's UTC?

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your reply. I am not getting any info on that. May I know how are you assuming that it is UTC provided ISO 8601 format?

Comment: That `Z` at the end is your answer: it's UTC (not because it's ISO 8601 - because ISO 8601 date format includes timezone details). Hence the reason I asked for you to include an example of datetime output.

Comment: Thanks David for this very useful info.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per [the docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet.publishedAt), any video's `publishedAt` property is given in ISO 8601 format:

> **snippet.publishedAt** (datetime)
>
> The date and time that the video was published. [...]
>
> The value is specified in [ISO 8601](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) format.

Looking further into the referenced ISO doc, it can be read that the designator `Z` means **`UTC`** time zone:

> Times are expressed in UTC (Coordinated Universal Time), with a special UTC designator ("Z").

Comment: It was great info. Thanks a ton. Special thanks to referencing the doc.